# Convert ImageSource to Bitmap

Tags: c#, wpf

Here is what i have so far

```
   OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog
        {
            CheckFileExists = true,
            Multiselect = false,
            Filter = "Images (*.jpg,*.png)|*.jpg;*.png|All Files(*.*)|*.*"
        };
     dialog.ShowDialog();
            {
                StrName = dialog.SafeFileName;
                ImageName = dialog.FileName;
                ImageSourceConverter isc = new ImageSourceConverter();
                if (ImageName != "")
                {
                    QRImage.SetValue(System.Windows.Controls.Image.SourceProperty, isc.ConvertFromString(ImageName));

                }

           }


        QRCodeDecoder dc = new QRCodeDecoder();




        dc.decode(new QRCodeBitmapImage(QrImage.Source as Bitmap));
```

and i cant read the MyImage with {Cannot convert type 'System.Windows.Media.ImageSource' to 'System.Drawing.Bitmap' 
}

Comment: Are you sure you need `Bitmap`? This is normally used in WinForms but not in WPF.

Comment: i save this QRimage with

Comment: QRImage.Source = YourUtilClass.loadBitmap(Creator);

Comment: and i cant read that saved image . what is the best way ?

Comment: Cast the Source value to BitmapSource, then do what's shown in the answers to the duplicate question. As a note, `QRImage.SetValue(System.Windows.Controls.Image.SourceProperty, isc.ConvertFromString(ImageName)` should be `QRImage.Source = (ImageSource)isc.ConvertFromString(ImageName)`.

Comment: @Clemens i have the error on last line (   dc.decode(new QRCodeBitmapImage(QrImage.Source as Bitmap));

Comment: Sure, because you haven't read the answer(s) on the duplicate question.